# Add margin to Appcompat actionbar popup menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-support-design

I am using appcompat actionbar. I want to add top margin to the overflow menu that opens on the top-right. Hence, increasing the spacing above it as you can see in the picture below. Right now the dropdown menu open on top of the 3 dots. How can I push it down?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Activity's default OptionItem menu, I guess you can't do it programmatically as the APIs just let you inflate it, thus adding/removing elements. Spacing should be fine tho, as the menu is standardized across every kind of layout.

What is the spacing problem you're having? Could you add a screenshot of your desired result?

A possible solution, not too dirty, would be using a custom style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   <item name="android:minWidth">XXdip</item>
   <item name="android:padding">XXdip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Please check the updates to my question. @Shine

Answer (score 0):

You can Toolbar instead of ActionBar

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
     android:id="@id/toolbar"
     android:background="@color/color_notification_toolbar"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

    <TextView
          android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_title_material_toolbar"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:textColor="@color/color_notification_title"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:id="@id/tvTimeLineTitle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/title" />
  
  /* add your menu items here as simple text views and 
    and give as much margins and paddings as you want  */
  
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```